# Проблема с назначением события динамически создаваемому элементу в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, события

```
var Link = document.createElement('a');
...
Link.onclick = MyFunction(Link);
// или Link.addEventListener('onclick', MyFunction(Link));
...
List.appendChild(Link);
```

Почему MyFunction сразу выполняется при создании элемента? Этого не надо...
Как правильно назначить событие динамически создаваемому элементу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что Вы ее вызываете.

```
Link.onclick = MyFunction;
// или Link.addEventListener('onclick', MyFunction);

function MyFunction(event) {
  var Link = this;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать...

Answer (score 1):

Вы таким образом запускаете функцию.
Надо что-то вроде:

```
document.addEventlistener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'brnPrepend'){//do something}
 })
```

Взято тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript